# Filter out objects from nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, filter

I need to filter this array so it is only left with the correct category codes

```
const yearLayers= 
     [
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "eventNodes": [
               {"header": "Pearls of Wisdom", "categoryCode": 3,}
             ]
        },
        {
            "year": 2017,
            "eventNodes":[
              {"header": "VENuS Satellite", "categoryCode": 2},
              {"header": "Hope for millions", "categoryCode": 1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "year": 2012,
            "eventNodes": [
              {"header": "green electricity Pioneer", "categoryCode": 1}
              {"header": "This is a header", "categoryCode": 3,}
              {"header": "more titles here", "categoryCode": 1,}
            ]
        }
    ]
```

This is a snippet of what the array looks like. I need to filter out the objects with the category code that does not === 1. So I left with an array with only categoryCode: 1.

```
const yearLayers= 
     [
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "eventNodes": []
        },
        {
            "year": 2017,
            "eventNodes":[
              {"header": "Hope for millions", "categoryCode": 1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "year": 2012,
            "eventNodes": [
              {"header": "green electricity Pioneer", "categoryCode": 1}
              {"header": "more titles here", "categoryCode": 1,}
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I have tried to use array methods, but I cannot seem to reach inside the nested array and the nested objects. I think I am missing something

```
const filteredArr = yearLayers
            .map(layer => layer.eventNodes)
            .map(node => node.categoryCode)
            .filter(node => node.categoryCode !== 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in combination with [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

```js
const formattedWorkbook = [{
    "year": 2016,
    "value": [
       {"header": "Pearls of Wisdom", "categoryCode": 3}
     ]
}, {
    "year": 2017,
    "value":[
      {"header": "VENuS Satellite", "categoryCode": 2},
      {"header": "Hope for millions", "categoryCode": 1}
    ]
}, {
    "year": 2012,
    "value": [
      {"header": "green electricity Pioneer", "categoryCode": 1},
      {"header": "This is a header", "categoryCode": 3},
      {"header": "more titles here", "categoryCode": 1}
    ]
}];

const filter = (data, category) => data.map(({year, value}) => ({
  year,
  eventNodes: value.filter(v => v.categoryCode == category)
}));

console.log(filter(formattedWorkbook, 1));
```

This avoids modifying the original data.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the result if you use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in the combination with a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const formattedWorkbook = [
  {
    year: 2016,
    value: [{ header: "Pearls of Wisdom", categoryCode: 3 }],
  },
  {
    year: 2017,
    value: [
      { header: "VENuS Satellite", categoryCode: 2 },
      { header: "Hope for millions", categoryCode: 1 },
    ],
  },
  {
    year: 2012,
    value: [
      { header: "green electricity Pioneer", categoryCode: 1 },
      { header: "This is a header", categoryCode: 3 },
      { header: "more titles here", categoryCode: 1 },
    ],
  },
];

const result = formattedWorkbook.map(({ year, value }) => {
  const filteredValue = value.filter((o) => o.categoryCode === 1);
  return { year, value: filteredValue };
});

console.log(result);
```

**2)**

```js
const formattedWorkbook = [
  {
    year: 2016,
    value: [{ header: "Pearls of Wisdom", categoryCode: 3 }],
  },
  {
    year: 2017,
    value: [
      { header: "VENuS Satellite", categoryCode: 2 },
      { header: "Hope for millions", categoryCode: 1 },
    ],
  },
  {
    year: 2012,
    value: [
      { header: "green electricity Pioneer", categoryCode: 1 },
      { header: "This is a header", categoryCode: 3 },
      { header: "more titles here", categoryCode: 1 },
    ],
  },
];

const result = formattedWorkbook.map(({ year, value }) => ({
  year,
  value: value.filter((o) => o.categoryCode === 1),
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You've mutated the original objects, which is not necessarily a good idea - it might not make a difference but can often lead to unintended side effects

Comment: Just FYI - answers which are code only with no explanation as to what has been done or what has been changed are less useful for future visitors